# Binary search tree routines fail to compile with pointer arguments

Tags: c++, pointers

Pretty new to C++ and I'm trying to write a Binary Heap calculator for a project due in a few days. Before I get to the Binary Heap I want to write a Binary Tree struct as a super class for the heap.

I'm still trying to wrap my head around pointers vs. reference and what each looks like upon assignment and WHEN I should define something as a pointer or reference.

Anyways here is some of the code that I'm curious about:

```
#include "BinaryTree.h"

int main(void){

    BinaryTree tempTree = new BinaryTree();
    BinaryNode* ptrToRoot;
    ptrToRoot = tempTree.getRootNode();

    int inputArr = { 5, 2, 7, 10, 11, 20, 1};

    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(inputArr) / sizeof(inputArr[0]); i++){
            tempTree.binaryTreeInsert(ptrToRoot, inputArr[i]);
    }

    tempTree.inOrderPrint(ptrToRoot);
}
```

And I'm getting an error from both the calls to binaryTreeInsert and inOrderPrint, both of which take ptrToRoot as an argument. The error says "Invalid arguments... valid candidates are BinaryNode *, int.

But when I hover over each argument in Eclipse, they both display that they are of the necessary type.

Am I defining the pointer incorrectly? Here is the header file of my BinaryTree class, in case it helps:

```
#ifndef BINARYTREE_H_
#define BINARYTREE_H_

#include "BinaryNode.h"

struct BinaryTree  {

    BinaryTree();
    virtual ~BinaryTree(){}

    BinaryNode rootNode;
    int noOfNodes;

    BinaryNode* getRootNode(){ return rootNode; }

    int countNodes(BinaryNode* ptRootNode);
    bool binaryTreeContains( BinaryNode* ptRootNode, int element);
    void binaryTreeInsert(BinaryNode* ptRootNode, int element);
    void preorderPrint( BinaryNode *ptRootNode );
    void postorderPrint( BinaryNode *ptRootNode );
    void inorderPrint( BinaryNode *ptRootNode );
};

#endif
```

Comment: should `getRootNode` not return `&rootNode` ? Or your member `rootNode` be a pointer ?

Comment: In BinaryNode.h, your getRootNode() is supposed to return a BinaryNode*, yet rootNode is a BinaryNode.

Comment: @Luc, yes you're right. I've changed the BinaryTree function getRootNode to return type BinaryNode&, however there are still errors.

Comment: @rharrison33 That is the header file for BinaryTree, and I've changed it to return BinaryNode& and then tried to have it return BinaryNode but still there are errors, neither change works.

Comment: quite a few compilation errors in here:
int inputArr = { 5, 2, 7, 10, 11, 20, 1}; should be int inputArr[] = { 5, 2, 7, 10, 11, 20, 1};
and take care of pointers, BinaryTree and BinaryTree* are different types

Comment: I suggest you start by googling "c++ pointer reference value tutorial" or something, and trying out small test programs. You really need to be intimate with that stuff, or C++ will be source of endless mysterious compilation errors (in the best case) and crashing programs (when you manage to fool the compiler).

Comment: I'm sorry but your code shows a fundamental misunderstanding of how to declare and use pointers. You have things like `BinaryTree tempTree = new BinaryTree();` and `BinaryNode* getRootNode(){ return rootNode; }`. `tempTree` isn't a pointer, so you can't initialize it with new. And `rootNode` isn't a pointer, so you cannot return it from a function that claims to return a pointer to a `BinaryNode`. You need to read your book or a good reference on pointers again before continuing. This seems like a somewhat decent reference: http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=529

Comment: @Gthoma2 you say that you changed "getRootNode to return type BinaryNode&". Do you know what `BinaryNode&` does and do you understand the difference between a reference and a pointer? You need to *stop coding* and start reading until you understand what pointers are, how they are declared, used and managed, and *then* you can get back to coding.

Comment: @NikB. But his assignment is due in two days. He's trying to write a BinaryHeap or at least a BinaryTree and he's not got the time!

Comment: @Gthoma2  Seriously there's a big difference between vaguely understanding what pointers and references are about and actually being able to use them. It will help to start with smaller code. Things get really difficult in C++ when you have multiple errors which all interact with each other, you try to fix one thing and other error pops up. You're never sure if what you're fixing is a real error or just the consequence of a different error elsewhere in your code. That's what is happening to you now. Write ten line programs, get them working, and build up from there.

Answer (score 0):

This may be at least part of your problem:

```
BinaryTree tempTree = new BinaryTree();
```

This line is incorrect; `new` is used to perform heap allocations, and it returns a pointer to the newly-allocated object.  However, your object is allocated on the stack.

Try changing this to:

```
BinaryTree tempTree;
```

This will construct a new object on the stack using the no-arg constructor.  This may resolve your problem, as the compiler may be confused about the type of this variable.

Comment: Ahhh, I must have missed that. Thank you. However, I'm still having the same errors.

Comment: Shouldn't it be: BinaryTree* tempTree?

Comment: @Sarang No, because there is no corresponding `delete`.  However, if a `delete` was added then that would be an acceptable answer as well.  However, I prefer stack-allocated objects where possible since there is no possibility of leaking the object if an exception is thrown.